# Need Exclusion XPath Example

Tags: xpath

For the xml below I only want to return the value of "DD" if "Q1" does NOT have a value of "Q1Yes".

```
<form>
<field name="ImageQualityRepeating" visible="true">
<rowinstance entryMod="Daily Diary" id="Daily Diary_1689194865577:0" index="1" lockedRow="false" newrow="true">
    <field name="Q1" visible="true">Q1Yes</field>
    <field name="Q1Yes" visible="true">true</field>
    <field name="QCDone" visible="true">QCDoneCheck</field>
    <field name="DD" visible="true">1</field>
</rowinstance>
<rowinstance entryMod="Daily Diary" id="Daily Diary_1689194865677:0" index="1" lockedRow="false" newrow="true">
    <field name="Q1" visible="true"/>
    <field name="Q1Yes" visible="true">true</field>
    <field name="QCDone" visible="true">QCDoneCheck</field>
    <field name="DD" visible="true">2</field>
</rowinstance>
</field>
</form>
```

For returning each now I have

```
/form/field[@name='ImageQualityRepeating']/rowinstance/field[@name='Q1' and @visible='true']/text()
```

returns "Q1Yes"

```
/form/field[@name='ImageQualityRepeating']/rowinstance/field[@name='DD' and @visible='true']/text()
```

returns "1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [a lot of Xpath to succes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milliarium_Aureum), but in this case I prefer
to put a predicate on `rowinstance` like this `rowinstance[not(field[@name='Q1']='Q1Yes')]`

and than get the correct value of field with the @name='DD'.

The XPath will be:

```
/form/field/rowinstance[not(field[@name='Q1']='Q1Yes')]/field[@name='DD']/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
/form/field[@name="ImageQualityRepeating"]/rowinstance[field[@name = "Q1"]/text() != "Q1Yes"]/field[@name="DD"]/text()
```

The key part is:

```
rowinstance[field[@name = "Q1"]/text() != "Q1Yes"]/field[@name="DD"]/text()
```

Which means:

find a rowinstance element that contains a field element with name "Q1" whose text value is **not** "Q1Yes" and then for that rowinstance show the text content of the field element with name "DD".

---

Alternately, you can take advantage of the `..` operator:

```
/form/field[@name="ImageQualityRepeating"]/rowinstance/field[@name="Q1" and text() != "Q1Yes"]/../field[@name = "DD"]/text()
```

---

Given this input:

```
<form>
<field name="ImageQualityRepeating" visible="true">
    <rowinstance entryMod="Daily Diary" id="Daily Diary_1689194865577:0" index="1" lockedRow="false" newrow="true">
        <field name="Q1" visible="true">Q1Yes</field>
        <field name="Q1Yes" visible="true">true</field>
        <field name="QCDone" visible="true">QCDoneCheck</field>
        <field name="DD" visible="true">1</field>
    </rowinstance>
    <rowinstance entryMod="Daily Diary" id="Daily Diary_1689194865677:0" index="1" lockedRow="false" newrow="true">
        <field name="Q1" visible="true">QCDone</field>
        <field name="Q1Yes" visible="true">true</field>
        <field name="QCDone" visible="true">QCDoneCheck</field>
        <field name="DD" visible="true">2</field>
    </rowinstance>
  </field>
</form>
```

Both of the above expressions return:

```
2
```

Comment: Ok thanks for that and maybe I didn't explain or there's just many possibilities butI need it to do a empty Q1 field. I updated OP xml sample. WIth your example an empty field does a "no match" on all of it